# Join lines of different aesthetics in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aesthetics, categorical

I'm trying to solve the following problem: how to join lines of different aesthetics/groups in ggplot and maintain the color of a certain group. It is best to see the examples below for a better understanding of what I mean.

Consider the following code:

```
set.seed(870123) 
library(ggplot2) 

example_data <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"),length.out = 20,by = "month"),
                           
                           Series = rnorm(20) + 1,
                           
                           Grouping = c(rep(c("Group1"),10),rep(c("Group2"),10)))

print(ggplot(example_data,aes(x = Date, y = Series)) + 
                  
                  
                  geom_line(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
                  
                  
                  geom_point(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
                  
                  scale_color_manual(values = c(Group1 = "blue", Group2 = "red")))
```

Which generates the plot:

[image: First Plot]

My problem is that ggplot won't join the lines where the grouping variable changes. I would like, for example, there to be a red line joining the last blue point to the first red point. One way to solve such issue would be to not specify any color aesthetic for the geom_line portion, as below, but this is **NOT** what I want:

```
print(ggplot(example_data,aes(x = Date, y = Series)) + 
                  
                  
                  geom_line() + 
                  
                  
                  geom_point(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
                  
                  scale_color_manual(values = c(Group1 = "blue", Group2 = "red")))
```

[image: Plot2]

The only way I am able to achieve what I want is with the really bad solution demonstrated below...

```
### Dirty Solution

temporary <- example_data[as.Date("2020-10-01") == example_data$Date,]
temporary$Grouping <- "Group2"

example_data <- rbind(example_data,temporary)

print(ggplot(example_data,aes(x = Date, y = Series)) + 
                  
                  
                  geom_line(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
                  
                  
                  geom_point(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
                  
                  scale_color_manual(values = c(Group1 = "blue", Group2 = "red")))
```

Plot generated, which is what I would like to achieve through a better solution:

[image: Plot3]

Is there any way to achieve what I want with ggplot2? I wasn't able to find a better solution.

Comment: Jon Spring, that worked nicely! I wasn't aware of geom_segment, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
ggplot(example_data,aes(x = Date, y = Series)) + 
        # use lag to connect backwards, lead to connect forwards
        geom_segment(aes(color = Grouping, xend = lag(Date), yend = lag(Series))) + 
        geom_point(aes(color = Grouping)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = c(Group1 = "blue", Group2 = "red"))
```

[image]